# Linking static c libraries and getting error recompile with -fPIC

Tags: android, c, cmake, android-ndk, ndk-build

Getting a lot of "undefined reference to" errors. What I am missing in my `CMakeLists.txt`? Am I not linking the library properly?

`native-lib` should be linked to `liblept.a` and `libtesseract.a` libraries which I am thinking is not being linked to these libraries.

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)


set(distribution_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../distribution)

add_library(lib_musireader STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_musireader PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${distribution_DIR}/musireader/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libMusiReader.a)

add_library(lib_lept STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_lept PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${distribution_DIR}/leptonica/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/liblept.a)

add_library(lib_tesseract STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(lib_tesseract PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${distribution_DIR}/tesseract/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libtesseract.a)
add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        native-lib
        SHARED
        native_lib.c)

find_library( 
        log-lib
        log)

target_include_directories(native-lib PRIVATE
        ${distribution_DIR}/musireader/include
        ${distribution_DIR}/leptonica/include
        ${distribution_DIR}/tesseract/include)

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        native-lib
        lib_musireader
        lib_lept
        lib_tesseract


        # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
        ${log-lib})
```

Here is build errors which I am getting:

```
Build command failed.

    Error while executing process /home/mushahid/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {--build /home/mushahid/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/x86_64 --target native-lib}
    [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native_lib.c.o
    [2/2] Linking C shared library /home/mushahid/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86_64/libnative-lib.so
    FAILED: : && /home/mushahid/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang  --target=x86_64-none-linux-android23 --gcc-toolchain=/home/mushahid/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 -fPIC --sysroot /home/mushahid/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-addrsig -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o /home/mushahid/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86_64/libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native_lib.c.o  /home/mushahid/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/musireader/lib/x86_64/libMusiReader.a /home/mushahid/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/leptonica/lib/x86_64/liblept.a /home/mushahid/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/tesseract/lib/x86_64/libtesseract.a /home/mushahid/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-android/23/liblog.so -latomic -lm && :
    /home/mushahid/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: error: /home/mushahid/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/leptonica/lib/x86_64/liblept.a: no archive symbol table (run ranlib)
    /home/mushahid/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: error: /home/mushahid/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/tesseract/lib/x86_64/libtesseract.a:1:1: invalid character
    /home/mushahid/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: error: /home/mushahid/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/musireader/lib/x86_64/libMusiReader.a(correlation.c.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'LeptMsgSeverity' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
    /home/mushahid/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: error: /home/mushahid/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/musireader/lib/x86_64/libMusiReader.a(dici.c.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'calloc' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
    /home/mushahid/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: error: /home/mushahid/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/musireader/lib/x86_64/libMusiReader.a(export.c.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'LeptMsgSeverity' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
    /home/mushahid/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: error: /home/mushahid/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/musireader/lib/x86_64/libMusiReader.a(interpreter.c.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'LeptMsgSeverity' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
    /home/mushahid/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: error: /home/mushahid/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/musireader/lib/x86_64/libMusiReader.a(log.c.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'boxCreate' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
    /home/mushahid/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: error: /home/mushahid/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/musireader/lib/x86_64/libMusiReader.a(preprocessor.c.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'pixCreate' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
    /home/mushahid/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: error: /home/mushahid/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/musireader/lib/x86_64/libMusiReader.a(recognition.c.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'boxCreate' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
    /home/mushahid/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: error: /home/mushahid/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/musireader/lib/x86_64/libMusiReader.a(rle.c.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'LeptMsgSeverity' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
    /home/mushahid/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: error: /home/mushahid/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/musireader/lib/x86_64/libMusiReader.a(segmentator.c.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'LeptMsgSeverity' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
    /home/mushahid/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: error: /home/mushahid/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/musireader/lib/x86_64/libMusiReader.a(segments.c.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'LeptMsgSeverity' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
    /home/mushahid/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: error: /home/mushahid/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/musireader/lib/x86_64/libMusiReader.a(serialization.c.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'fseek' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
    /home/mushahid/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: error: /home/mushahid/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/musireader/lib/x86_64/libMusiReader.a(staff.c.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'calloc' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
    /home/mushahid/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: error: /home/mushahid/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/musireader/lib/x86_64/libMusiReader.a(staff_detector.c.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'staffaCreate' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
    /home/mushahid/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: error: /home/mushahid/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/musireader/lib/x86_64/libMusiReader.a(sym_recognizer.c.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'boxCreate' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
    /home/mushahid/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: error: /home/mushahid/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/cpp/../../../../distribution/musireader/lib/x86_64/libMusiReader.a(utility.c.o): requires dynamic R_X86_64_PC32 reloc against 'LeptMsgSeverity' which may overflow at runtime; recompile with -fPIC
    /home/mushahid/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: warning: shared library text segment is not shareable


    /home/mushahid/Project/Project/sources/correlation.c:13: error: undefined reference to 'LeptMsgSeverity'
    /home/mushahid/Project/Project/sources/correlation.c:13: error: undefined reference to 'returnErrorInt'
    /home/mushahid/Project/Project/sources/correlation.c:15: error: undefined reference to 'LeptMsgSeverity'
    /home/mushahid/Project/Project/sources/correlation.c:15: error: undefined reference to 'returnErrorInt'
```

and lot more reference errors

Comment: In unix (etc) you sometimes have to ensure that a library appears on the linker command line many times. For example if libX.a defines foo, uses bar and libY.a uses foo and defines bar then the linker may need to see -l libX -l libY -l libX -l libY. I don't know if android is like this, but it may be worth checking if the undefined references are in fact in libraries you are linking, and if so see if you can persuade your tool to pass the list many times to the linker

Comment: It actually attempts to link with `liblept.a` and `libtesseract.a`, but finds these file not to be a libraries: look for error `no archive symbol table (run ranlib)` and `invalid character` in your log.

Comment: have you got answer to your question?

Comment: yes i resolved my error by recompiling the libraries with the -fPIC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my errors by simply recompiling the libraries with **-fPIC** flag.

like this in makefile:

```
CFLAGS += -fPIC
CPPFLAGS += -fPIC
```

Comment: Native code for Android should *always* be compiled with -fPIC. It's a basic requirement for the platform IME.

Answer (score 0):

you are linking against `lib_lept`, but your library name is `liblept`, so you need to change all your occurrences of `lib_lept` to `liblept`, or change your library name `liblept.a` to `lib_lept.a` whichever you prefer.

This also applies to `libtesseract` and other libraries.